# How to deduct shipping costs in runtime onepage checkout process?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

I want to deduct shipping costs in runtime onpage checkout process? I have check process, but I am not getting success till. If anyone know about this, please explain me in brief.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Shathish, I want to reduce shipping costs, which we have to choose during shipping method. Atlast in "Order Review" tab it should be show amount with reduce shipping cost.

Comment: how you wanna reduce it? Is it based on user input or you have a calculation by yourself (admin side)?

Comment: I want to put logic overthere, But I have no idea, where can I put my logic.

Comment: All right, you can use a event observer to do this task. Observe `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` event and write your logic in the observer and set the shipping cost there.

Comment: Hey @Shathish add your comment as answer so OP can vote for it. Your solution is a really good one so it deserves a place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, you can use a event observer to do this task. Observe `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` event and write your logic in the observer and set the shipping cost there.

Follow these steps:

> in app/etc/modules/Yournamespace_Yourmodulename.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
                <observers>
                    <set_shipping_cost>
                        <class>Yournamespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setShippingCost</method>
                    </set_shipping_cost>
                </observers>
            </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodulename/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Yournamespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer{
    public function setShippingCost($observer)
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

        $quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quoteid=$quote->getId(); 
        if($quoteid) {                    
        try{
                $address=$quote->getShippingAddress();
                if($address->getAddressType()=='shipping'){
            //    echo '<pre>'; print_r($events->getQuoteAddress()->getData()); exit;
                $price=40; /* you can add the logic to calculate the shipping cost here */

                // Find if our shipping has been included.
                $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                         ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

                foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
                    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
                        $rate->setPrice($price);
                        $rate->save();

                    }
                }
                    $this->collectTotals($quote,$price);
                }            
                $quote->collectTotals();
            } catch (Exception $e) {            
                Mage::logException($e);
                $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }



    public function collectTotals($quote,$price){
        $quoteid=$quote->getId(); 
        $shippingcode='freeshipping_freeshipping';
        if($quoteid) {                    
                try{
                $quote->setSubtotal(0);
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);
                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingcode)/* ->collectTotals() */->save();
                $quote->save();
                foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
                    $address->setSubtotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                    $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                    $address->collectTotals();

                    $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                    $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );

                    $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                    $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

                    $address->setShippingAmount($price);
                    $address->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
                    $address->save();
                }

                    $response['message'] = 'Succcess';
                } catch (Exception $e) {            
                        Mage::logException($e);
                        $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

> **note:**
>
> replace `$price=40;` with your logic, in the Observer.php
>
> thanks to Pradeep [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/316685/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have follow your step but there might be some problem. When checkout process come at "Order Review" Step, it's show me "Shipping method has not been selected yet". And During Shipping Method to Order Review steps shipping cost display as 0 amount.

Comment: did you tweak anything else in checkout process, coz it works for me , checked both in ce 1.7.0.2 and 1.8.0.0 and even in EE