# shipping fee calcutation modification

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, shipping

In table rate shipping method handling charges are either fixed or percentage of shipping fee. but I want little modification in it. say `x` is shipping amount as per table rate. `y` is fixed surcharge and `z` is tax which is fixed.

So total shipping fee will be `x * (1 + y%) * (1 + z%)`

How to apply this formula to calculate total shipping charges?

Comment: try to use `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` event to get 'x' (when table rate is applied) in its observer and do your calculation and then set the shipping charge. for example/ reference visit `http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/how-to-deduct-shipping-costs-in-runtime-onepage-checkout-process/9297#9297`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` and at the same time implement `implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface` class. See the below pseudo code.

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Carrier_Myshippingmethod
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
      // Modify the shipping charge here.
}
}
```